# BASH For Loop Array - unable to echo unknown subdirectory

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, directory

I'm a beginner to bash scripting and been writing a script to check everyday logs where multiple folders and multiple subfolders are involved and I'm bit stuck at one point.

```
home
    └── usr
        └── logs
            └── day
                └── location
                    └── Primary
                        ├── 2022102801
                        │   └── 01MMSS
                        ├── 2022102802
                        │   └── 02MMSS
                        └── 2022102803
                            └── 03MMSS
```

The above tree has the folders which im trying to construct as a path inside the script.

here is my code where i have used bash arrays inside loop to do a check for all subfolders in the `Primary` folder. I was able to get the first set of subfolders and I'm bit unsure on how to get the second set of subfolders since their name varies with time (minutes and seconds eg 01MMSS 02MMSS 03MMSS)

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
export CUSTOM_PATH=/home/usr/logs/day/location
export DST=("$DATE"01 "$DATE"02 "$DATE"03)
for i in "${DST[@]}"; do
    #GETS THE FIRST SET OF SUBFOLDERS
    echo "Primary Alerts: $CUSTOM_PATH/Primary/$i"
    #TRYING TO GET THE SECOND SET OF SUBFOLDER
    #HERE I HAVE USED * to get the unknown directory 
    mypath="$CUSTOM_PATH/Primary/$i/*/"
    echo "$mypath"
done
```

Comment: Off topic side note: Strictly avoid all-caps variable names. Those are, by convention, reserved for environment variables and you don’t want to clash with them at random.

Comment: Side note 2: To traverse a directory tree recursively, use a (recursive) Bash function. Or use `find`; it’s not pure Bash, but it can do the job.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want the code to do. Are you expecting the `*` wildcard to expand to a list of existing directories? Wildcards don't expand when double-quoted (or in some other contexts). If you want to match subdirectories, use something like `for subdir in "$custom_path/Nowcasting06/$i"/*/; do` (note that the `*` is outside the quoted part).

Comment: consider `find /home/usr/logs/day/location/Primary -type d` which may do what you want or you can adapt